# Python webscraping find_all("a") in specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am new in web scraping and I working on my little easy project.

The task is getting names of `"cameras"`, their `"prices"` and `"quick specs"`

(from: https://www.dpreview.com/products/cameras/all?page=1).

The last mentioned I can get when I 'click' on the camera to route me to the new URL.

When I inspected the page I have to get URL from there, however with just:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

I'll get all the links (so some extras, like logins, social media, etc):

What I would like to do is get before mentioned just from the specific class.

Can you help me with it? (or at least point me to the tutorial where this is discussed?).

I am using `BeautifulSoup in Python3.`

Comment: You need to use a [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) or [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) selector (I never used beautifulsoup, but I think you're already using xpath selectors, you just don't know it)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the necessary information by first anchoring your search to the `td` product listings with `class="product"`:

```
import requests, typing
class Camera(typing.NamedTuple):
  info:typing.List[str]
  quicklook:str
  price:str

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.dpreview.com/products/cameras/all?page=1').text, 'html.parser')
headers = [['div', 'name'], ['div', 'specs'], ['div', 'prices']]
vals = [[(lambda x:getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A') if b != 'name' else [getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A'), i.a['href']])(i.find(a, {'class':b})) for a, b in headers] for i in d.find_all('td', {'class':'product'})]
final_result = [Camera(*i) for i in vals]
```

Output:

```
[Camera(info=['Fujifilm X-T3', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fujifilm_xt3'], quicklook='26 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$1,499.00 - $2,898.00'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS R', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos_r'], quicklook='30 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Sony Cyber-shot DSC-HX99', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dschx99'], quicklook='18 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 720 mm (30×)', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Sony Cyber-shot DSC-HX95', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dschx95'], quicklook='18 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 720 mm (30×)', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Nikon D3500', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_d3500'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$496.95 - $596.95'), Camera(info=['Nikon Z6', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_z6'], quicklook='25 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$1,996.95 - $3,443.90'), Camera(info=['Nikon Z7', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_z7'], quicklook='46 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$3,396.95 - $4,843.90'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-LX100 II', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/compacts/panasonic_dclx100ii'], quicklook='17 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 75 mm (3.1×)', price='$997.99 - $1,095.98'), Camera(info=['Leica M10-P', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/leica/slrs/leica_m10_p'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Canon PowerShot SX740 HS', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/compacts/canon_sx740hs'], quicklook='21 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 960 mm (40×)', price='$399.00'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm XF10', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/compacts/fujifilm_xf10'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen', price='$499.00'), Camera(info=['Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 V(A)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dscrx100m5a'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 70 mm (2.9×)', price='$898.00 - $1,096.00'), Camera(info=['Nikon Coolpix P1000', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/compacts/nikon_cpp1000'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | 24 – 3000 mm (125×)', price='$996.95 - $1,041.90'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm instax mini 90 NEO CLASSIC', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/compacts/fujifilm_instax_mini_90'], quicklook='N/A', price='$112.00 - $121.30'), Camera(info=['Leica C-Lux', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/leica/compacts/leica_c-lux_2018'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 360 mm (15×)', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX100 VI', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dscrx100m6'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 200 mm (8.3×)', price='$1,198.00 - $1,265.16'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm X-T100', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fujifilm_xt100'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$599.00 - $899.00'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-TS7 (Lumix DC-FT7)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/compacts/panasonic_dcts7'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 28 – 128 mm (4.6×)', price='$447.99'), Camera(info=['GoPro Hero (2018)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/gopro/actioncams/gopro_hero_2018'], quicklook='10 megapixels | Compact sensor', price='$189.90 - $233.39'), Camera(info=['Sony Alpha a7 III', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/slrs/sony_a7iii'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$1,998.00 - $4,396.00'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS M50 (EOS Kiss M)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eosm50'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$629.00 - $948.48'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS Rebel T7 (EOS 2000D)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos2000d'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS 4000D', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos4000d'], quicklook='18 megapixels | 2.7″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Pentax K-1 Mark II', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/pentax/slrs/pentax_k1ii'], quicklook='36 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$1,896.95 - $2,296.95'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm X-H1', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fujifilm_xh1'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$2,648.00 - $3,548.00'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-GX9', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/slrs/panasonic_dcgx9'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-ZS200 (Lumix DC-TZ200)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/compacts/panasonic_dczs200'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 360 mm (15×)', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Olympus PEN E-PL9', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/olympus/slrs/olympus_epl9'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='$599.00 - $699.00'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-GF10 (GF90)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/slrs/panasonic_dcgf10'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm X-A5', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fujifilm_xa5'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$599.00 - $799.00'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm FinePix XP130', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/compacts/fujifilm_xp130'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3″ screen | 28 – 140 mm (5×)', price='$169.00 - $179.00'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-GH5S', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/slrs/panasonic_dcgh5s'], quicklook='10 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='$2,297.99 - $3,395.98'), Camera(info=['Leica CL', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/leica/slrs/leica_cl'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$3,995.00'), Camera(info=['Panasonic Lumix DC-G9', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/slrs/panasonic_dcg9'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='$1,497.99 - $3,995.98'), Camera(info=['Rylo Camera', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/rylo/actioncams/rylo_camera'], quicklook='N/A', price='$497.85 - $499.00'), Camera(info=['Xiaomi Mi Sphere 3.5K', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/xiaomi/actioncams/xiaomi_mi_sphere_3p5k'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 2 lens(es) | Compact sensor', price='Check prices'), Camera(info=['Sony Alpha a7R III', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/slrs/sony_a7riii'], quicklook='42 megapixels | 3″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$3,213.00 - $3,997.00'), Camera(info=['Canon PowerShot G1 X Mark III', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/compacts/canon_g1xiii'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 72 mm (3×)', price='$1,099.00'), Camera(info=['GoPro Hero6 Black', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/gopro/actioncams/gopro_hero6_black'], quicklook='12 megapixels', price='$401.97 - $412.98'), Camera(info=['Sony Cyber-shot DSC-RX10 IV', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dscrx10iv'], quicklook='20 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 600 mm (25×)', price='$1,698.00 - $1,788.93'), Camera(info=['Fujifilm X-E3', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fujifilm_xe3'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$899.00 - $1,449.23'), Camera(info=['Ricoh Theta V', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/ricoh/actioncams/ricoh_theta_v'], quicklook='12 megapixels | 2 lens(es) | Compact sensor', price='$396.99 - $616.98'), Camera(info=['Olympus OM-D E-M10 III', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/olympus/slrs/oly_em10iii'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3″ screen | Four Thirds sensor', price='$549.00 - $799.00'), Camera(info=['Sony DSC-RX0', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dscrx0'], quicklook='15 megapixels | 1.5″ screen', price='$598.00 - $646.00'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS M100', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eosm100'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$449.00 - $679.00'), Camera(info=['Nikon D850', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_d850'], quicklook='45 megapixels | 3.2″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$3,296.95 - $6,896.90'), Camera(info=['Leica TL2', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/leica/slrs/leica_tl2'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3.7″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$2,195.00'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS 6D Mark II', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos6dmkii'], quicklook='26 megapixels | 3″ screen | Full frame sensor', price='$1,599.00 - $2,848.00'), Camera(info=['Canon EOS Rebel SL2 (EOS 200D / Kiss X9)', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos200d'], quicklook='24 megapixels | 3″ screen | APS-C sensor', price='$549.00 - $948.00'), Camera(info=['Nikon Coolpix W300', 'https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/compacts/nikon_cpw300'], quicklook='16 megapixels | 3″ screen | 24 – 120 mm (5×)', price='$386.95')]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not what I specifically wanted, however thank you for sharing it is still very useful for me.
To clarify - "quick spec" is longer list of specification which can be seen only when you click ona model of the specific camera. That's why I wanted to get all URLs of all models in order to collect longer list of spec from that URLs.

Comment: @KarolinaBzd Please see my recent edit. The final result now stores a `Camera` object with an attribute `info`, storing a list with the camera's name and link to "quick spec". Is that closer to your desired output? Do you need to scrape the quick-spec page as well?

Comment: @@Ajax1234 thank you very much! You helped me quite a lot. I wanted to scrape quick-spec as well, however I decided that for now it's good as it is and later I'll try do it by myself (thanks to your code now I know how to do it).